# Android - Firebase RecyclerView Search

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, retrofit, firebaseui

I am developing an application, the application already registers new clients in Firebase. I was able to load the information from Firebase in RecyclerView using FirebaseUI, but I also need to put a search.

But I still have doubts about how best to do this, if anyone has any examples, it is always useful.

I was thinking of using the `Retrofit`, passing the link https://appname-f7ei5.firebase.com/clients to get `JSON`, does it work?

Or would I have to create a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and a `ViewHolder`, but how would I load the information directly from Firebase?

For the search, the best way is to use a `getFilter()` in the Adapter?

Comment: Well it's probably a duplicate question. Try to search some: https://www.google.nl/search?q=search+in+firebase+database&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIR756IR756&oq=Search+in+firebase&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60j0l2.4616j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Anyways, I'll give you some codes to start what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did for getting my Posts title on FireBase Database. Try to play with (child) and `orderByChild` and you'll see how it works. In another words, Imagine the `child` as the root in the head of the firebase database then collapse it and use `orderByChild` to get the under root items.

```
Query queryRef = mReference.child("posts").orderByChild("title").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\uf8ff");
                    queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                                for (DataSnapshot postsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    final Post post = postsSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
 // and the rest ...
..
..
..
```

And in your case, It's gonna be :

```
Query queryRef = mReference.child("users").orderByChild("username").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\uf8ff");
```

This will return the user's usernames by your query search.